# Import external Xcode project in a Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project named "A" where I dragged and dropped a second external Xcode project named "B" with extension .xcodeproj.

The problem is that B refers to a local path on my machine. This causes that if I transfer A to another computer, Xcode can't obviously resolve the reference to my local path for B.

How can I fix that?

I want a way to transfer A with all its dependencies so that it will work fine on another computers/users.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to setup a property as the base path and use it in B application. In order to do that, Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) helps.